# count the output python

Tags: python, for-loop, count

I want to compare two lists:
-CAGGTGGTGAT (my_list[0])

--CAGGTGTGAT (my_list[1])

And I want to find how many pairs I have (A-A, C-C, G-G, T-T) and how many mismatches.
I have this code for the mismatches

```
for i in range(len(my_list[0])):
        if my_list[0][i-1]!=my_list[1][i-1]:
            print("mismatch")
```

How can i count how many mismatches are printed?
I tried to use count, but it counts pairs and mismatches.
I want to count only the mismatches that are printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()` with `zip()` to count the mismatches:

```py
mylist = ["-CAGGTGGTGAT", "--CAGGTGTGAT"]

mismatches = sum(a != b for a, b in zip(mylist[0], mylist[1]))
print(mismatches)
```

Prints:

```
5
```

Comment: it returns the error 'Counter' object is not callable. I'm new to python so I don't really know what I can do.

Comment: @anastasia You've probably assigned to name `sum` before. Don't use python builtin names as variable names.

Comment: if i didn't assign sum before, what might be the problem?